# Methods of storing permanent data in java

Tags: java, storing-information

I am currently doing a programming assignment and it says that we should
"store all the data in a data file and need to check the compatibility of the user PIN and account no. validity"

Unfortunately my lecturer has not taught us about data files, and when I googled I found two different answers,

1. Store data in notepad (.txt) file
2. Store data in csv file

MY QUESTION IS WHICH ONE IS A DATA FILE? and how do you retrieve the user PIN (after its typed from buffer reader) to check whether both are correct?
Any Help is GREATLY APPRECIATED!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from wikipedia:

> A data file is a computer file which
>   stores data for use by a computer
>   application or system.

So both a `*.txt` file and a `*.csv` file are data files.

A `*.csv` (comma-seperated values) file is in essence a `*.txt` file that separates your values by a `,`

The 2 methods you found should do about the same, but it will be easier to use the csv-method.

Answer (score 4):

The *easiest* way is using the `Properties` class. It stores key/value pairs and can persist the data to a properties files. Here's a working example:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("johndoe.pin", "12345");
p.store(new FileWriter("myfile.properties", "");
```

and reading:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileReader("myfile.properties", "");
```

The check will be done with the properties object:

```
public boolean isValid(String user, String pin) {
  return pin.equals(p.getProperty(user + ".pin"));
}
```

It is easy *but* of course there's no encryption. The file is stored in plain text including the PINs.

Comment: i did this as well, but the properties object (p) does not hve any available methods. so the setProperty, store and load methods all result in errors. However, the object creation statement does not have any errors

Comment: @Yoosuf - the fully qualified classname is [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Comment: there's error in p.store. It should be : p.store(new FileWriter("myfile.properties"), ""); This compiles!

Comment: I have an application where I want to store the attributes of java Objects persistently, Is the class `Properties` useful for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether it's txt or csv. You can even save it in xml.
Don't get confused with file extension. The only thing you should care about is "how you can save/load those data".

1. To save in .txt is fine but perhaps you will need to define your own 'formatting' just to make sure that you can load that data.
2. If you save it in .csv is also nice since you don't have to invent your own 'formatting'. Just follow several legacy format like delimiter, encloser etc.
3. To save in another format is also good. For example, XML. But, again, you need to follow a legacy formatting in XML like DTD.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is another method of persistent storage.
You can create a class that implements Serializable with a field for each piece of data you want to store.  Then you can write the entire class out to a file, and you can read it back in later.  I believe the Serializable interface outputs the class into some sort of binary/hex representation.

There are other ways to to do serialization without using the standard Java serialization, like you can use a JSON library.

Comment: If you need to have a text file specifically, it is also possible to use the standard Java serialization to output an XML file representing the object. An explanation of how to achieve this can be found here: http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/1377961/Serializing-Java-Objects-as-XML.htm