# Cannot find symbol - class FileWriter. How to fix?

Tags: java, windows-7, persistence, bluej

So I was trying to find out how to store data permanently in Java and I came across this post: [Methods of storing permanent data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583779/methods-of-storing-permanent-data-in-java)

And I found this answer:

The easiest way is using the Properties class. It stores key/value pairs and can persist the data to a properties files. Here's a working example:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("johndoe.pin", "12345");
p.store(new FileWriter("myfile.properties", "");
and reading:

Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileReader("myfile.properties", "");
The check will be done with the properties object:

public boolean isValid(String user, String pin) {
  return pin.equals(p.getProperty(user + ".pin"));
}
```

It is easy but of course there's no encryption. The file is stored in plain text including the PINs.

I have already imported the Java.util.Properties package, and the rest of my code is working, but I get the error "Cannot find symbol - class FileWriter"

Here is the complete code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AdminGUI extends JFrame {
    Bank AccountHandler[];
    int c = 0;

    JLabel pinL;
    JLabel balL;  
    JLabel nameL;   

    JTextField pinTF;
    JTextField balTF;
    JTextField nameTF;
    JTextField resultTF;
    JTextArea listTA;

    JButton ClearB;
    JButton ListB;
    JButton CreateB;
    JButton ExitB;

    ClearButtonHandler clbHandler;
    ListButtonHandler lbHandler;
    CreateButtonHandler cbHandler;
    ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

    Properties prop[];

public AdminGUI() 
{
    AccountHandler = new Bank[10];

    setTitle("The Bank");

    pinL = new JLabel("Enter desired PIN #: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    balL = new JLabel ("Enter the initial deposit: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    nameL = new JLabel ("Enter your name: ", JLabel.RIGHT);


    pinTF = new JTextField(10);
    balTF = new JTextField (10);
    nameTF = new JTextField (10);
    resultTF = new JTextField (10);
    listTA = new JTextArea (5, 10);

    ClearB = new JButton("Clear List");
    clbHandler = new ClearButtonHandler();
    ClearB.addActionListener(clbHandler);

    ListB = new JButton("List Accounts");
    lbHandler = new ListButtonHandler();
    ListB.addActionListener(lbHandler);

    CreateB = new JButton("Create");
    cbHandler = new CreateButtonHandler();
    CreateB.addActionListener(cbHandler);

    ExitB = new JButton("Exit");
    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
    ExitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);

    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));

    pane.add(pinL);
    pane.add(pinTF);
    pane.add(balL);
    pane.add(balTF);
    pane.add(nameL);
    pane.add(nameTF);
    pane.add(ClearB);
    pane.add(resultTF);
    pane.add(ListB);
    pane.add(listTA);
    pane.add(CreateB);
    pane.add(ExitB);

    setSize(600,400);
    setVisible(true);
}
public class CreateButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        int pin;
        double bal;
        String name;

        pin=Integer.parseInt(pinTF.getText());
        bal=Double.parseDouble(balTF.getText());
        name=nameTF.getText();

        AccountHandler[c] = new Bank(pin, bal, name);
        prop[c] = new Properties();
        prop[c].setProperty("acct." + c, AccountHandler[c].pinString());
        prop[c].store(new FileWriter("bankacct.properties", ""));


        pinTF.setText("");
        balTF.setText("");
        nameTF.setText("");
        resultTF.setText("Created. Welcome, " + name + ".");
        c++;
    }
}
public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public class ListButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String list = "";
        for(int i = 0; i != c; i++) {
            list = list.concat(AccountHandler[i].toString());
        }
        listTA.setText(list);
    }
}
public class ClearButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            listTA.setText("");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdminGUI rectObject = new AdminGUI();
    }
}
```

And here is the section giving me trouble:

```
AccountHandler[c] = new Bank(pin, bal, name);
prop[c] = new Properties();
prop[c].setProperty("acct." + c, AccountHandler[c].pinString());
prop[c].store(new FileWriter("bankacct.properties", ""));
```

I am a beginning java programmer and I'm new at this so I'm sorry if I'm missing an easy solution.

Comment: you need to import FileWriter, like every other class in java.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import java.io.FileWriter